# django or gunicorn can't read linux environment variable

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, django-deployment

in an Ubuntu 16.04 server, I run following commands in the python shell:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ
```

and the output is:

```
environ({'DJANGO_DB_USERNAME': 'siteuser', 'DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD': 
'123456','DJANGO_SECRET_ KEY': 'xvia%9op!4q$%w@o8t9f%pa%sdfsdfbu+sdfsdf', 
'DJANGO_DB_NAME': 'some_name', ..., ..., other keys})
```

it means environment variables have been set correctly.
but when I run the `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` for checking gunicorn status, the `os.environ` doesn't work properly.
this is the output, when gunicorn runs the django:

```
environ({'LANGUAGE': 'en_US:en', 'PATH': 
'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin', 
'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'config.settings.production', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 
'gunicorn/19.8.1', 'USER': 'mojtaba'})
```

the following keys `DJANGO_DB_NAME, DJANGO_DB_USERNAME, DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD, DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` are not found. also other variables are not shown.

who knows what's the problem??

Comment: is user you test environ in the python-cli the same as you run in the supervisor?

Comment: @BearBrown Could you give me more information? how to know?

Comment: try to add to the output `os.environ.get('USER')`

Comment: @BearBrown the key `USER` with value `mojtaba` is in the keys in both situation. when I run the command in python-cli or when gunicorn runs the django, in both situation it is in the environment variables list...

Comment: how do you set env values for python shell?